# Upgrading camera_platform_interface from 1.0.4 to 1.2.0 results in camera not working

Tags: flutter

There's no error logs printed, so it's difficult to provide some more information about what is causing this. With the same code base, same camera plugin version (0.6.3+2), if I run flutter pub upgrade and camera_platform_interface bumps from 1.0.4 to 1.2.0, parts of our app that use the camera stop working (black screen).

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.5, on Microsoft Windows [VersiÃ³n 10.0.19042.685], locale es-ES)
    • Flutter version 1.22.5 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision 7891006299 (3 weeks ago), 2020-12-10 11:54:40 -0800
    • Engine revision ae90085a84
    • Dart version 2.10.4

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\crist\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\crist\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[!] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • ONEPLUS A5000 (mobile) • f2eb43ee • android-arm64 • Android 10 (API 29)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [dependency override](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#dependency-overrides) to workaround the problem.

Adding the following to your pubspec.yaml should solve the issue:

```
dependency_overrides:
  camera_platform_interface: ">=1.0.4 <1.1.0"
```